# What is "ex-Government Official" meaning?

Tags: meaning

I read the Declaration of Compliance of my company and it has a parapharase below:

> The undersigned has made truthful declarations to [Company X] regarding:
>
> - His/her current or prior role as a Government Official; and/or
> - His/her relationship to any Government Official or to any ***ex-Government Official***.

I don't understand "**ex-Government Official**" meaning so I looked up and searched "ex-goverment offical" word on many dictionary and resources but I can't find out any information.

Please help me ! **What's the ""ex-Government Official" meaning?**

Comment: Seeing as you didn't question "Government Official" on its own, then presumably it's only the "ex-" part you're struggling with. What did you find when you searched for the meaning of "ex"?

Answer (score 1):

In this context, the prefix *ex-* means former. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ex-#Prefix) has this definition:

> former, but still living (almost always used with a hyphen)
>   *ex-husband, ex-president, ex-wife*

So an ex-government official is someone who was previously a government official.

Comment: That "still living" part is interesting. In my experience divorced people seem to keep using the term "ex-husband/wife" even if the ex has died, and why not? Deaths in those cases do not change their marital status. I imagine that definition is trying to say that a spouse who died while still married would not usually be termed an "ex".